# PHP process HTTP headers

Tags: php, http, http-headers, header

How do I obtain the HTTP headers in response to a POST request I made with PHP?

Comment: Well...I think you should give a *little* more details. Code i.e.

Comment: I have a POST request to send to a second page and I wish to send the request and obtain the response headers of the second page in variables form somehow. This is how I have learnt it is done with CURL http://it.toolbox.com/wiki/index.php/Use_curl_from_PHP_-_processing_response_headers I was looking for a simpler method

Comment: it seems like that class already abstracts the curl stuff away pretty nicely.  what's the problem with using it?

Comment: the problem is that I am behind a proxy which has http authentication. it does not support that directly and I do not know CURL to change the script

Comment: Arrgh. I wish I could edit this question.

Comment: So you need to set a Proxy-Authenticate header? Do you need to detect a 407 "Proxy Authentication Required" response? Need much more info about the overall goal, not just the step you're having problems with.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

How did you issue the POST?  I use a socket and then read back the response where I get headers and body.

Comment: i want to use a socket but I don't know how exactly to code it. From my C++ knowledge, I know I can do this job easily if I create a socket but how do I go about it in PHP?

Comment: I plucked this out of an HTTP class I wrote, so all the niceties - error handling, etc - are missing, but I think it shows the basic steps.

$fp = @fsockopen(HttpComm::$host, HttpComm::$port, $iErrno, $sErrStr, (int)self::$iTimeoutConnectionSecs);

// send request
fputs($fp, $sHttpString, strlen($sHttpString));

// this will get the string of headers
$sResponse   = stream_get_line($fp, 1024, "\r\n\r\n");

// I break the HTTP response headers apart like so
HttpComm::$headers   = explode("\r\n", $sResponse);

If you continue reading from this point you then it's the body of the response.

Comment: Sorry about the formatting.  I looked under faq for code formatting

Answer (score 2):

Create an [HTTP stream context](http://php.net/manual/en/function.stream-context-create.php) and pass it into `file_get_contents()`. Afterwards, you can:

```
$metaData = stream_get_meta_data($context);
$headers = $metaData['wrapper_data'];
```

Answer (score 1):

you will find them in the superglobal `$_SERVER` ... anything that starts with `HTTP_` should be a header ... it depends on the server, how well this will work ...

greetz

back2dos

Comment: -1. He's asking about getting headers when his script is an HTTP client.